# JS Игра | В кликер не добавляется нужное количество

Tags: javascript, веб-сайт

Я долго мучился со стилями и у меня получился сайт, без JS. Я добавил JS к моей игре. Игра кликер. На верху показывается счётчик кликов, ниже получить клик. Ещё ниже есть магазин клик-power, чтобы за один клик получать не один, а два, пять и больше. Я получил баг в магазине. Я начал с покупки одного клика. По логике, он должен был проверить, если кликов достаточно на покупку, то вычесть из глобальных кликов цену,
`clickPower` отобразить на сайте. У меня получилось, но не так, как надо. Я сначала докликиваю до 5 кликов, покупаю один клик-power, и вижу, что у меня счётчик кликов обнулился. Потом я нажимаю получить клик, получаю два клика (что так и должно быть), а при повторном, получаю один. Помогите.

```js
var clicks = 0;
var clickPower = 1;
var upgradeCost1 = 5;
var upgradeCost2 = 25;
var upgradeCost3 = 50;
var upgradeCost4 = 250;
var upgradeCost5 = 500;

const onClick = () => {
    document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = clicks + clickPower;
    clicks++;
}
const increaseOne = () => {
    if (clicks >= upgradeCost1) {
        clicks = clicks - upgradeCost1;
        clickPower += 1;
        document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = clicks;
    }
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', onClick)
document.getElementById('upgrade-button-1').addEventListener('click', increaseOne)
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
}

.app .count-back h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.app .click-menu #big-btn:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1, 0.9)
}
.app .click-menu #big-btn {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: unset;
}
.app .upgrades>ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 300px;
}
.app .upgrades>ul li {
    padding: 3px;
}
.app .upgrades>ul li span {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.app .upgrades>ul li .upgrade-button {
    width: 216px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.app .click-power-block {
    padding-left: 380px;
}
.app .click-power-block > p {
    font-size: 36px;
}
.app .upgrades .upgrade-button {
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.app .upgrades .upgrade-button:hover {
    transform: scaleX(1.05);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>xClicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class='count-back'>
            <h1>Кликов: <span id='clicks-count'>0</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class='click-menu'>
            <center>
                <button id="big-btn">Кликнуть</button>
            </center>
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="upgrades">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span id="cost-upgrade-1">Цена: <span class="cost-money">5</span> кликов&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                <button class="upgrade-button" id="upgrade-button-1">Увеличить на 1 клик</button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span id="cost-upgrade-5">Цена: <span class="cost-money">25</span> кликов&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                <button class="upgrade-button" id="upgrade-button-5">Увеличить на 5 кликов</button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span id="cost-upgrade-10">Цена: <span class="cost-money">50</span> кликов&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                <button class="upgrade-button" id="upgrade-button-10">Увеличить на 10 кликов</button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span id="cost-upgrade-50">Цена: <span class="cost-money">250</span> кликов&nbsp;</span>
                                <button class="upgrade-button" id="upgrade-button-50">Увеличить на 50 кликов</button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span id="cost-upgrade-100">Цена: <span class="cost-money">500</span> кликов&nbsp;</span>
                                <button class="upgrade-button" id="upgrade-button-100">Увеличить на 100 кликов</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="click-power-block">
                        <p>Ваш текущий клик составляет <span id='click-power'>1</span> клик(ов)</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если вопрос решен, отметьте свой ответ принятым (поставьте галку слева от ответа). Добавлять "решено" в заголовок вопроса не нужно.

Comment: @insolor, "Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 16 часов"

Comment: Это не отменяет того что я выше написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Я просто эти клики увеличивал на 1, хотя у меня клик-power больше, я изменил строчку `clicks++;` на `clicks = clicks + clickPower;`

Comment: Можно `clicks += clickPower`.